# windows service: failed to debug

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-services

I was following the instructions in official msdn to debug my windows service:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3.aspx 
however, after I attached the process to debugger and tried to Stop the service in Service Control Manager, the process just disappeared and the debugger thus exit without hitting any break point.
I chose the process name as the executable of my window service application.
Did i do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When the debugger is attached to a process, clicking the blue Stop button usually terminates the process, that's why you saw the service process disappear. Of course at that point, breakpoints won't be hit since all the modules for that process are unloaded. If you want to detach from the service and still let it run, in the **Debug** menu in Visual Studio click **Detach All**.

It feels like though you're having issue debugging your service. Debugging Windows services is a little different than debugging other projects in Visual Studio. Just clicking the green "play" button doesn't automatically put the service in debug mode. In many cases, the breakpoint needs to be set in the `OnStart()` method since that is where the problem occurs. They way I always debug Windows services is by putting a `Thread.Sleep()` statement on the top of the `OnStart()` method, before the program attempts to do anything else. You can specify how long you want the main thread to be asleep, and then use this time to attach the VS debugger to the Windows service. For example:

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
 {
     Thread.Sleep(10000);

     // Rest of the code
 }
```

Will give you 10 seconds to attach to the service. Install the service, start in in the `Services` window, and then attach to it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this at the top of your service....

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

or if possible, convert your service to use http://topshelf-project.com/.  Which supports debugging in visual studio.  And has an added benfit of allowing the service to "run as console app" for debugging.